# Group of two lines element with html/css

Tags: html, css

To resume, I want to make something like this:

[image]

Each text has its own value below, as I'm new to html/css I tried many solutions, but when it comes to css I find out that's not correctly done, can anyone help or at least point of which direction should I take?

Best regards

Comment: Take a look at flexbox and just play around with positioning elements with it. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It looks like you may want to make a [table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). If not, it would be helpful if you could provide more information. Maybe post some example code.

Comment: Good ideas, I'm trying both suggestions, I'll leave a feedback once i'm done